# Excel VBA - search, offset, replace

Tags: vba, excel

I have a settings sheet with unique identifiers in column D and replacement values in column F. I need to:

- loop through all serial numbers in sheet `settings`column D
- find the row with the same serial in sheet `test` column A
- get the replacement value from `settings` column F
- replace the data in column B on the `test` sheet, in the same row as the previously searched serial

sounds simple enough but I am getting a type mismatch error when defining the `for` and `to` statement with the code below.

```
Sub Replace_List()
Dim rList As Range, cell As Range, n As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")
        Set rList = .Range("D4", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each cell In rList
        For n = cell.Value To cell.Offset(0, 2).Value Step 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test").Columns("B:B").Replace What:=n, _
                              Replacement:=cell.Offset(0, 2).Value, _
                              LookAt:=xlWhole
        Next n
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Replaced all items from the list.", vbInformation, "Replacements Complete"

End Sub
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong here are appreciated.
Thanks,
A2k

**EDIT**
Screenshots below:

Settings - I am looking up the survey ID and want to replace the **original** date with the **correct** one
[image]

Comment: What is the value of `cell.Value` and of `cell.Offset(0, 2).Value` when it crashes?

Comment: `cell.value` is the serial number it should look up and `cell.offset(0,2).value` is the replacement value

Comment: But what are the values when it crashes?  E.g. is it bigger than 2,147,486,647?

Comment: cell.Value or cell.Offset(0, 2).Value is probably not integer/long, that's my guess

Comment: cell.value is a 10 digit serial number, hence set it as long. replacement value is usually a date or text

Comment: You can't loop from a 10 digit number (even if it is below 2147486647) to a date or text.  What is the loop intended to do?

Comment: would it be possible to provide a screenshot of cell.Value and cell.Offset(0, 2)?

Comment: added a screenshot of the settings sheet data. I am searching for the survey ID in column D and want to replace the result with the value in column F.

Comment: You `For` is going from a long value in `cell.value` to a date value in `cell.Offset(0, 2).Value` _(two columns to the right on the same row)_, and it is not clear what you are trying to do by looping this row. Perhaps you can try removing the for loop altogether, and just use the replace.

Comment: @rayzinnz That was my first thought too - but the OP needs to do the find in column A and the "replace" in column B, i.e. it isn't really a "find and replace" operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use `Find` to find each occurrence, and then replace the value using an `Offset` of the found location:

```
Sub Replace_List()
    Dim rList As Range, cel As Range, n As Long
    Dim fnd As Range
    Dim fndFirst As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")
        Set rList = .Range("D4", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each cel In rList
        Set fnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=cel.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
            fndFirst = fnd.Address
            Do
                fnd.Offset(0, 1).Value = cel.Offset(0, 2).Value
                Set fnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Columns("A:A").FindNext(After:=fnd)
            Loop While fnd.Address <> fndFirst
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Replaced all items from the list.", vbInformation, "Replacements Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: @Armitage2k Oops - silly mistake there - fixed (hopefully) - also changed the line before the `Loop While` - not sure whether that would also cause problems (I don't use `Find` much) but decided to change it anyway

Comment: never rush your lunch break ;) Thanks a lot, it works perfectly now, appreciate the help!

Comment: @Armitage2k It's a good thing I am in a cubicle so that no-one can see what I am doing :D